# KSH shell that counts lines of files in directory

Tags: linux, ksh

This is the prompt:

> Write a Korn shell script (and show the code for it here) that will determine which file in a directory has the maximum number of lines (this may be different than the file that has the maximum number of bytes). After determining the file with the maximum number of lines, the script will print out the name of the file and the number of lines. The script must only focus on files and ignore subdirectories. The command `wc` may be helpful. Do not write this script to be executed interactively.
>
> #### Requirements:
>
> The script must allow either no arguments or 1 argument.
>
> 1. If zero arguments are specified, the script by default will examine the files in the current directory.
> 2. If 1 argument is specified, the argument must be the name of a
>      directory. The script will then examine the files in the specified
>      directory.
>
> The script must be able to handle the following error conditions:
>
> 1. More than 1 argument is specified.
> 2. The specified argument is not a directory.
>
> The script file name must be: `maxlines.sh`.
>   The script permissions should be `705`.

This is the code I have:

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# -gt 1];then
    echo "There must be 0 or 1 arguments"
    exit
fi
if [ -d "$1" ];then
    cd $#
    fi
    max=0
for file in *
do
    lines=$(( $( wc -l < "$file" ) ))
    if [ $max -lt $lines ];then
        max=$lines
    fi
done
```

Any advice would be appreciated.  I am new to Linux so this is quite frustrating. When I run it the output looks like this:

```
./maxlines.sh[2]: [: ']' missing
./maxlines.sh[9]: cd: 1: [No such file or directory]
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
wc: standard input: Is a directory
```

Comment: You have basic syntax errors. Suggest you first go through a shell programming tutorial - because it is obvious you haven't done that. And then code a few lines at a time rather than try to do the whole thing at once. For example, get your first `if` block working. That will at least progress your knowledge on basic shell script syntax (hint: The `if` condition needs to end with a `;` before the `then` and you need a space before the `]`).

Comment: I had added the ";" early in the process but it kept giving me errors with them.  It was indeed because I had overlooked the space as you said.  Thank you for pointing that out.  It is not just syntax errors that are the problem though.  I have fixed them and now the output is the same just without the syntax error flags.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Doesn't the error message itself give you a fairly obvious thought to ponder? Your script tries to `wc` everything within the target directory. And that error message tells you that some (sub)directories are being passed to `wc`. It obviously does not make sense to count the number of lines in a directory. And that's exactly why `wc` issues that message.

Comment: Also, it seems you know what `$#` is as you use that to verify whether the script is being called correctly or not. So, with that in mind, what do you expect `cd $#` to do? Perhaps you mean `cd $1`. Seems like a basic typographic error. And one that reading of the error message and a code inspection should pick up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JeremyBrooks already explained, there are a lot of errors in your script, but you're not on completely the wrong path.

This is my fix:

```
#!/bin/ksh
    if [ $# -gt 1 ];then
            echo "There must be 0 or 1 arguments"
            exit
    fi
    if [ -d "$1" ]
    then
            cd $1
    fi
    max=0
    for file in $(find . -name "*" -type f)
    do
            lines=$(( $( wc -l < "$file" ) ))
            if [ $max -lt $lines ];then
                    max=$lines
                    maxFile=$file
            fi
    done
    echo "file[$maxFile] - max[$max]"
```

With `for file in $(find . -name "*" -type f)` you'll get only files; in your previous version you'll get also the directories, but you want to count the file lines.

Another way to prevent exclude directories is `for file in $(ls -l * | grep -v "^d"|awk '{print $9}'`, but that is not fast as `find`.

You also forgot to keep the file name when you get the max line number, so in the `if` you have to add `maxFile=$file`.

Then don't forget to print out the result: `echo "file[$maxFile] - max[$max]"` after the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to combine commands with pipes:

```
 wc -l * 2>/dev/null| grep -v total | sort -n | tail -1 | sed -r 's/\s*([0-9]*) (.*)/\2 has \1 lines./'
```

You should still handle the parameters (about what you have but use spaces in the if-statement around the `[` and `]`). And what to do with a dir without files:

```
output=$(same_command_as_above)
if [ -z "${output}" ]; then ...
```